# 502 Bad Gateway with NGINX, Gunicorn, Django

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I tried setting up a project with NGINX and Gunicorn using this [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-centos-7). However, I keep getting a 502 Bad Gateway error.

Here is my server conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name nexus-staging.chop.edu;
    access_log /webapps/nexus/logs/nginx/nexus-staging.chop.edu.access.log main;
    error_log /webapps/nexus/logs/nginx/nexus-staging.chop.edu.error.log warn;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /webapps/nexus/static_cdn;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/webapps/nexus/nexus.sock;
    }
}
```

Here is my gunicorn service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/nexus
User=svc_dgdnexus
Group=dgd_svc
WorkingDirectory=/webapps/nexus
ExecStart=/webapps/nexus/pyvenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 4 --bind unix:/webapps/nexus/nexus.sock django_config.wsgi:application --name nexus --access-logfile /webapps/nexus/logs/gunicorn/nexus-staging.chop.edu.access.log --error-logfile /webapps/nexus/logs/gunicorn/nexus-staging.chop.edu.error.log

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This is the nginx error:

```
2017/02/17 22:55:23 [error] 36168#0: *1 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 10.249.27.89, server: nexus-staging.chop.edu, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/webapps/nexus/nexus.sock:/", host: "nexus-staging.chop.edu"
```

This is the gunicorn error:

```
[2017-02-17 22:53:59 -0500] [36143] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 36143
[2017-02-17 22:53:59 -0500] [36145] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 36145
[2017-02-17 22:55:23 -0500] [36137] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:36140)
[2017-02-18 03:55:23 +0000] [36140] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 36140)
[2017-02-17 22:55:23 -0500] [36202] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 36202
```

Comment: If this happens randomly then there can be various reasons, have you checked ram usage with `free -mh` ? If ram is an issue, you can add a little bit swap or try reducing number of workers initially? Also keep in mind gunicorn has 30 seconds timeout setting that can be extended as shown here: http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#timeout

Comment: yep I checked ram usage and there is plenty of ram available. It is just the initial django setup, so it shouldn't be a long request. I have a feeling it has to do with NGINX conf, I just can't seem to pin it down.

Comment: Is there a wsgi.py file in django_conf package/dir? It might not pointing the right wsgi.  You can also experiment disabling nginx, binding gunicorn directly to 0.0.0.0:80 and try to make a request.

Comment: Strange. When I bind directly to `0.0.0.0:8000` and visit the hostname:8000 it says page can't be found...

Comment: Is it from django or browser? If browser, then you might need to add port forwarding on your server for 8000 (security group inbound for ec2 for e.g.). One more level down, you can also run ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001 and try that if it is reachable.

Comment: from browser. When I run on my machine locally it works just fine. But on the remote host it doesn't. Frustrating

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136012/discussion-between-zatta-and-genomics-geek).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution:

Here is my server conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name nexus-staging.chop.edu;
    access_log /webapps/nexus/logs/nginx/nexus-staging.chop.edu.access.log main;
    error_log /webapps/nexus/logs/nginx/nexus-staging.chop.edu.error.log warn;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /static/ {
        alias /webapps/nexus/static_cdn/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
}
```

Here is the gunicorn service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target
After=syslog.target

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/nexus
User=svc_dgdnexus
Group=dgd_svc
WorkingDirectory=/webapps/nexus
ExecStart=/webapps/nexus/pyvenv/bin/gunicorn django_config.wsgi --workers 4 --access-logfile /webapps/nexus/logs/gunicorn/nexus-staging.chop.edu.access.log --error-logfile /webapps/nexus/logs/gunicorn/nexus-staging.chop.edu.error.log
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Make sure your ALLOWED_HOSTS in django settings is something like: `.nexus-staging.chop.edu`. The `.` is critical for it work.